# how works kWebServiceURL?

Tags: iphone, function

I read some code with this kWebServiceURL(@"somepage.php"). How works this function?
Thank you

Comment: Can you post the context in which it's used.  Usually variables with the k prefix are constants, like: #define kWebServiceURL @"somepage.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like a custom function. search the code you are using that in. It may be that they are creating a web service url out of the string being passed in.